# How to use a matplotlib custom style with embedded figure in pyqt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have embedded a matplotlib figure into my PyQt5 GUI and I'm having trouble specifying a custom style. Only the font size of the legend is changing. Is there a difference to the use of this with an embedded plot using the QT5Agg backend?

Normally I can specify a custom style sheet using the following but this doesn't seem to be working with the embedded figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('./Plotting styles/wfa setup graphic.mplstyle')
```

the style sheet is as follows:

```
backend: Qt5Agg
# Labels

axes.titlesize : 30
#axes.labelsize : 20

#Lines
lines.linewidth : 3
lines.markersize : 10

#Axis
axes.spines.right : False
axes.spines.top : False
xtick.labelsize : 40
ytick.labelsize : 40

#Legend
legend.fontsize : 20
```

I'm implementing the figure using the following:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np


class MplWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
        

# define plot widget
plt_stg_res2 = MplWidget()

# define figure
fig = plt_stg_res2.canvas.figure

# clear the figure
fig.clf()

# create axes
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

# apply custom style
plt.style.use('./Plotting styles/wfa setup graphic.mplstyle')
#plt.style.context(matplotlib_styles.plot_style_stage_overlays())

# These are the colors that will be used in the plot
ax1.set_prop_cycle(color=[
    '#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a',
    '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94',
    '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d',
    '#17becf', '#9edae5'])

# plot equity curve from all passes
for opt_pass in self.passes.values():
    # Plot each line separately with its own color.
    trade_time = np.array([self.start_date] + opt_pass.deal_time)
    balance = np.cumsum(np.array([self.start_balance] + opt_pass.deal_profit))
    line, = ax1.plot(trade_time, balance, label=f'Pass {opt_pass.pass_num}', lw=1)
    ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.05), loc='right')

ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel(f"Balance ({opt_inputs['currency']})")

# Remove the plot frame lines. They are unnecessary here.
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(True)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(True)

ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=8,
                bottom=True, top=False, labelbottom=True,
                left=False, right=True, labelleft=True)

# Add Title
fig.suptitle(f'Equity Curves for each Optimisation Pass '
             f'in {self.stage_name}', fontsize=12, ha="center")

plt_stg_res2.canvas.draw()
```